# DateTimePicker not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

why is DatetimePicker not working properly.
On edit, I set the default date and time to the Date of the model.

It is working only for the date. But for the time is is keeping its time to 00 00.

[image]

The date is put from the database into the datefield and the datetimepicker.
I updated the datepicker with the addon timepicker.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Afspraken.Datumafspraak)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Afspraken.Datumafspraak, new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Afspraken.Datumafspraak)
</div>

@section scripts {
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
                dateFormat: "d-m-yy",
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                defaultDate : '@Model.Afspraken.Datumafspraak.Day'+'-'+'@Model.Afspraken.Datumafspraak.Month'+'-'+'@Model.Afspraken.Datumafspraak.Year' + " "+ '@Model.Afspraken.Datumafspraak.Hour'+':'+'@Model.Afspraken.Datumafspraak.Minute',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                useCurrent: false,
                yearRange: "-4:+10",
                minuteStep: 30,
                todayBtn: true,
                controlType: 'select',
                oneLine: true
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var afspraak = _context.Afspraken.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Afspraakid == id);
    if (afspraak == null)
        return HttpNotFound();
    var viewModel = new AfsprakenFormViewModel
    {
        Afspraken = afspraak,
        City = _context.Cities.ToList(),
        TypeAfspraak = _context.TypeAfspraak.ToList()
    };
    return View("Edit", viewModel);
}
```

Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Datumafspraak { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is not working. What are you expecting and what is actually happening?

Comment: Upon edit, defaultdate is set correctly from the model into the DateTimePicker, but time is not set: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSDT3.gif

Comment: Just delete your `defaultDate` and use `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Afspraken.Datumafspraak, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", new { ... })`

Comment: And as a side note, your `[DataType]` and `[DisplayFormat]` attributes are not applicable when using `TextBoxFor()` - they are only respected when using `EditorFor()`

Comment: @stephen: ok, you're right.  I alreadyused DefaultDate with only Date, but now with time as add-on,I'd better set it in the view.  Thank you. this is working.

Answer (score 0):

In @Html.TextBoxFor you can add this `data-date-format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP"`

But we need more informations to know what is wrong

Comment: the data seems to bind correctly, because the textbox is giving the correct info:

Comment: I added the controller too